# DirectCompute from C background

Tags: c, algorithm, directcompute

Interested to develop some image analysis algo.

Real beginner in GPU computing, I was years ago a physics researcher used with C programming, working only on algo not on GUI side, using simple tools such as smart text editor and gcc.

Not interested in CUDA since didn't want to be stuck with NV hw, done quick test on OpenCL just setting up the env using Visual Studio Express + AMD SDK + first basic kernel require messing around to create a simple "hello word" equivalent.

I want the simplest possibile starting path to focus on algo development, i.e. matrix multiply in 5 min and running. Using DC will I find a smoother start considering my background? Working on an old machine with DC 5.0 support.